# Repeatedly spawning the same process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need some help figuring this out please.

The issue I've run into is that process 1 runs with a for loop inside, data is gathered and after I need to spawn a process to analyse it.

This code I have will only create each process once, how can repeat process 2 for each data() for loop?
TIA

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def data(q):
    dosmth()
    for i in range(5):
        fetch_data()
        q.put('data has been added')


def analysis(q):
    msg = q.get()
    print(msg)
    process_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=data, args=(q,)), Process(target=analysis, args=(q,))]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def data(q):
    dosmth()
    processes = []
    for i in range(5):
        fetch_data()
        q.put('data has been added')
        processes.append(Process(target=analysis, args=(q,)))
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()


def analysis(q):
    msg = q.get()
    print(msg)
    process_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=data, args=(q,))]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Or even better pass directly the data, not the queue to analysis. The bad part is that if you get lots of data you will start lots of process which become inefficient.

Another way to do it to have analysis loop while `q.get()` so that analysis can process more than one piece of data per call. Then you can instantiate as many analysis as you think it's optimal, regardless of how much data there is.